# Why do characters in anime rarely change their hairstyles?

Tags: tropes

In real life, people wouldn't change their hairstyles every month, but they will change one day. However, most of the characters in anime never change their hairstyles, even if the time span of the story last for years.

Why do characters in anime rarely change their hairstyles?

Comment: Frame challenge: changing hairstyles is actually a pretty common way to symbolize character development (and/or a timeskip). The obvious reason it tends not to happen otherwise is simply that hairstyle is part of a character design.

Comment: And animators don't want to take the extra effort. They can reuse the character design and frame how they want and not doing creating new frames.

Answer (score 5):

Keeping the character's look the same is easier for the animators, because it allows the reuse of art work, and for the audience because it makes recognizing the character easier.

This also allows changing the hairstyles for actual purposes, to symbolize character development, or to reflect that there has been a long period of time skipped.  Having characters change their hair styles just because means that these changes lose impact.